# CX_Freeze - Building a .msi with Admin permissions

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am trying to create an executable from my python/tkinter code that can be installed by other users. I have been able to successfully do this with cx_Freeze, however, the .exe is unable to write to files in the working or specified directories.
After researching this issue, I discovered that this may be because the .exe does not have the appropriate read/write permissions. 
Sure enough, when I tried running the .exe with Admin permissions, I was able to perform the relevant functions. Since this worked, I was wondering whether there is a way to build the cx_Freeze .msi while specifying user permissions in the setup.py file. I have not been able to find any documentation about this, so I am hoping that you can help with this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this question while looking for a solution to the same thing, so I thought I'd share how I solved it. The short version - `C:\Program Files` isn't intended to be a folder with permissions to any program.

Programs in windows are expected to use AppData folders for writing their local data, in theory nothing should change in `C:\Program Files` from the moment of installation. Windows has environment variables to tell you where app data is supposed to be saved. For me running this:

```
app_data_folder = os.environ['ALLUSERSPROFILE']
```

Gives me the shared data folder for all users (in my case `C:\ProgramData`). My program can then create a folder within it, and do whatever I want to the files there with full permissions.

If the shared data folder for all users isn't what you're looking for, you should use one of these to get the AppData folder for the specific user running the program:

```
os.environ['APPDATA']  # in my case: 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Roaming'
```

OR

```
os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA'] # in my case: 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local'
```

And repeat what is said above (create your own folder in there, proceed to save and read files as you please)